# Android AlarmManager call running activity

Tags: java, android

I have an alarm manager to check if my activity needs to be updated every 30 minutes or so.
I want to send from the alarmManager to my running activity a message to it be reloaded.
How i would do so? I tryied using startActivity from within the alarmManager but i was unsuccessful.

Comment: Sorry for this off-topic comment, but you might be interested on [this proposal at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese). We need more users with 200+ rep committing to it, so the site can reach beta. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with Activity's [onNewIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) method? In your activity class you should be able to do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent i){
    refresh();
}
```

You could also pack some extra data into the PendingIntent you raise with AlarmManager and check it from onNewIntent if you need more logic.